# MikTeX 2.9: libertine suddenly broken

Tags: miktex, libertine

MikTeX 2.9: 'libertine' seems to have broken at some point today (9 Dec leading into 10 Dec). The following code should produce some material in libertine:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}
1234567890 This text should be typeset in Libertine
\end{document}
```

Expected output:

[image]

Actual output:

[image]

(I should stress that I have seen the output of a specific TeX file change over the course of the day, without any modifications to the file -- I was getting the right output in the afternoon, and now it's not working.)

Completely uninstalling and reinstalling MikTeX didn't fix the problem. Further, different repositories seem to have different packages. For example, anorien.csc.warcick.ac.uk has the 'libertine' package, whereas mirror.ox.ac.uk has libertine-legacy and libertineotf. (Edit: I just checked back, and it has now switched to 'libertine'.)

For what it's worth, the `xelatex` error messages are as follows:

> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/fxl/m/n' undefined
>   (Font)              using`EU1/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 5.
>
> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `EU1/fxl/bx/n' undefined
>   (Font)              using`EU1/fxl/m/n' instead on input line 6.

Does anyone know what's happening with the repositories? Is anyone able to get libertine to work on MikTeX?

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
fontspec.sty    2012/05/06 v2.2b Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX
   expl3.sty    2012/11/21 v4332 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper
 l3names.sty    2012/09/24 v4230 L3 Namespace for primitives
l3bootstrap.sty    2012/07/16 v3991 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
l3basics.sty    2012/11/10 v4306 L3 Basic definitions
 l3expan.sty    2012/08/28 v4149 L3 Argument expansion
    l3tl.sty    2012/09/28 v4244 L3 Token lists
   l3seq.sty    2012/09/09 v4212 L3 Sequences and stacks
   l3int.sty    2012/09/26 v4237 L3 Integers
 l3quark.sty    2012/11/04 v4268 L3 Quarks
   l3prg.sty    2012/09/09 v4212 L3 Control structures
 l3clist.sty    2012/09/09 v4212 L3 Comma separated lists
 l3token.sty    2012/11/01 v4251 L3 Experimental token manipulation
  l3prop.sty    2012/09/09 v4212 L3 Property lists
   l3msg.sty    2012/09/09 v4212 L3 Messages
  l3file.sty    2012/09/09 v4212 L3 File and I/O operations
  l3skip.sty    2012/11/04 v4260 L3 Dimensions and skips
  l3keys.sty    2012/11/02 v4256 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces
    l3fp.sty    2012/11/10 v4305 L3 Floating points
   l3box.sty    2012/11/04 v4259 L3 Experimental boxes
l3coffins.sty    2012/09/09 v4212 L3 Coffin code layer
 l3color.sty    2012/08/29 v4156 L3 Experimental color support
l3luatex.sty    2012/08/03 v4049 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
l3candidates.sty    2012/11/09 v4298 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  xparse.sty    2012/11/21 v4332 L3 Experimental document command parser
fontspec-patches.sty    2012/05/06 v2.2b Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX/Lu
aLaTeX
fixltx2e.sty    2006/09/13 v1.1m fixes to LaTeX
fontspec-xetex.sty    2012/05/06 v2.2b Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX/LuaL
aTeX
 fontenc.sty
  eu1enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
  eu1lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
xunicode.sty    2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many oth
er characters in Unicode lower plane
 eu1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
   xetex.def    2009/11/22 v0.94 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)

fontspec.cfg
libertine.sty    2011/06/06 - 5.1.2: Font libertine - (License GPL) Michael Nie
dermair
lettrine.sty    2012/07/20 v1.63 (Daniel Flipo)
lettrine.cfg
    calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
     fxl.inc
     fxb.inc
     fxk.inc
     fxi.inc
   t3cmr.fd    2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
 ***********
```

Comment: Make sure the server you update from is up-to-date itself, check on http://miktex.org/pkg/repositories. Make sure to use both the "Admin" and the normal update programs if you have both. Afterwards, put `\listfiles` at the beginning of your MWE, recompile, and edit the file list from the log file into your question.

Comment: May be this can help http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10967/15717

Comment: Using anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk, which is listed as 'no delay'. Once I install via admin, I am blocked from installing as user.  File list above. (And, thank you!)

Comment: @Mohan Hmm, that `libertine.sty` (and some packages related to it) is not up-to-date, on my MiKTeX 2.9 it is `libertine.sty    2012/12/01 (Bob Tennent) Supports Libertine and Biolinum fonts for all LaTeX engines.`. Make sure `libertineotf` and `libertine-legacy` are uninstalled; usually they should get uninstalled during the updating process automatically.

Comment: I don't think I ever had them installed. (I just saw them on the list.)  Could I ask what repository you have your package manager connected to?

Comment: (But am currently searching my whole hdd for libertine files, to make sure.)

Comment: @Mohan I usually just use the closest repository, which for here often happens to be mirrors.med.harvard.edu. The `libertine.sty` your document uses is from `libertine-legacy`, so it must be somewhere. Try `kpsewhich libertine.sty` in the command line, that will display the location of the `libertine.sty` MiKTeX would use first, I think. (Dont forget to use `@username` replies to notify other users of your responses!)

Comment: @doncherry: You are an absolute star. There was a stray 'libertine.sty' in the scratch directory I was building in. (I didn't even realise it was possible to override packages like that.) I'm sorry for taking up so much of everyone's time.

Comment: @Mohan Glad I could help `:)`. I think there's a certain order of places in which MiKTeX looks for files, and the current directory has the highest priority. Since I don't think it's very likely that anybody else will have the same problem as you, we should probably close this question.

Comment: Of course. (Or delete it?)

Comment: @Mohan Not sure about deletion, we don't delete stuff very often, probably less often than we should. I guess you can ask one of the moderators in [chat] or flag your question for mod attention asking about potential deletion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The libertine font type one has been changed for two times, the last one not long ago.

There are two new packages supporting a part of the old libertine font. See question [how does libertine type1 work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76305/how-does-libertine-type1-work?lq=1).

You can -- if you have an archive of the old libertine font (`libertine-legacy`) -- install the old font in a local texmf tree and use the old font without changing your existing tex documents.

Comment: I tried libertine-legacy earlier and couldn't get it to work.